# Testing for crash with google test

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

In Google Test I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
void ImNotNiceToPointers( void* p )
{
  ((int*)p) [5] = 1;
}

TEST( Bla, BlaBla )
{
  EXPECT_NO_CRASH( ImNotNiceToPointers(NULL) );
}
```

And I would like the output to show error that the statement actually made the process die abnormally.

Is there any support for this in Google Test? I'm pretty sure how I would implement it myself, so I'm almost certain it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a death test to isolate a crash:

```
EXPECT_EXIT(ImNotNiceToPointers(p); exit(0), ExitedWithCode(0), '');
```

However, I recommend against using death tests. Using a death test incurs the overhead of launching a subprocess whether there is a crash or not. But if you simply leave your code as is and your test crashes, you will know, and will be able to fix it. Tracing the origin of the crash is easy with the help of tools like Valgrind or Dr. Memory.

Comment: It seems that death tests is for asserting that it dies. I.e i get an error if it doesn't, I'm kind of looking for the other way around. And for your other remark: This is not for unexpected crashes, this is for making sure an API can accept all kinds of wacky input whith proper error handling, which involves passing null pointers etc. Catching the crash as a controlled error allows for continous execution of tests without interrupt.

Comment: In the code above, the death test assertion verifies that the code exits normally using ExitedWithCode(0) predicate. If the ImNotNiceToPointers() call executes normally, the control passes to the exit() function, which forces the child process to exit normally, satisfying the test condition. If the  ImNotNiceToPointers call crashes, ExitedWithCode(0) predicate will not be satisfied, failing the assertion.