# Is there a way to expect global exception in GTest?

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I have a scenario where a call `SendFeedback()` sends a message and returns successfully. The message is received by another thread which throws. `EXPECT_THROW` doesn't work because `SendFeedback()` does not throw itself. Is there a way to expect this kind of exceptions?

pseudo-code:

```
auto listener = Listener();
auto sender = Sender();
...
sender.SendFeedback();

// listener throws due to unexpected feedback. This exception is to be expected
```

Comment: Exceptions can't cross over to other threads. Where do you expect the exception to end up? Because if it is not caught somewhere it will simply cause the program to abort and if it is caught, then gtest will never see it.

Comment: well, "program is aborted" is the expected behavior in real life. But how do I expect this behavior in GTest?

Comment: Maybe EXPECT_DEATH is the solution? https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/assertions.md#death-assertions-death

Comment: @R2RT That might be the way to go

Comment: If crashing the app is the expected behaviour, death tests are your best bet. They have quite a few quirks, so read the docs carefully. But I'd first consider if it's really correct behaviour to crash a program and if I could change the architeture in such a way that I wouldn't have to write such tests (e.g. on unit test level, I should be able to test receiver in separate, without threads).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Testing for crash with google test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569713/testing-for-crash-with-google-test) (although the answer is not very informative).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I agree that death tests would be duplicated answer, but does it mean it is duplicated question? Maybe there is some way to capture/catch uncaught exception from other thread. Some magic using `std::set_terminate`?

Comment: I tried `std::set_terminate` , it catches but still aborts and test fails.

Comment: btw the Death Test was the solution for my situation. @R2RT if you want to write an answer, please go ahead so that I can mark as correct answer.

Comment: @R2RT Even with `std::set_terminate` you are required by standard to end the program. The non-deathtest possibility would be decoupling the test and testing separately sender and listener (without threads), but we don't know if this is reasonable for the test goals. One could consider a separate program that executes program under test and expects a crash under given condtitions, but it's basically an elaborate reimplementation of death test in GTest (and it requires a separate program, so you can't just use two components and expect it to work).

Comment: IMO death test to expect uncouth exception is bad since it will hide actual problem when it accrues (actual crash). It is hard to give a good advice for this scenario without details. Maybe you should replace `std::thread` with `std::async` store a future. Then `EXPECT_THROW(future.get(), ...);`. Anyway uncouth exception in thread is a fishy thing.

Comment: Note that death test are for planned process termination (like some function calls `std::exit(1)`), not for a crashes. Some tech lead coin a phrase for that: "We do not design crashes" (when intern closed bug "working as designed").

Comment: @MarekR Totally valid point. In this scenario, we expect the program to terminate (by throwing an unhandled exception), since there is no logical reason to continue execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly what you asked for, but GTest have for mechanism for [death tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#death-tests), where you can assert that given invocation would crash the program.
Uncaught exception invokes `std::terminate`, which by default invokes `std::abort`, thus will pass the assertion.

I've made small proof of concept to verify it works:

```cpp
void delayed_uncaught_exception()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::thread thread([] { throw std::runtime_error("Error"); });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
}

TEST(MyDeathTest, DelayedException)
{
    ASSERT_DEATH(delayed_uncaught_exception(), "");
}
```

Although, I strongly agree with discussion under the question, that death tests maybe not the best fit for this test scenario and in long-run I'd recommend redesigning the flow.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote similar test programs for a communication library. I used an independent communication channel for sending the result back to the gtest thread. The receiver thread has to catch the exception and send the result back to the gtest thread of process. This communication channel can be just a global variable or some kind of message queue, but the 2 threads have to be synchronized. I found barriers useful for that.